# Apache subdomain

Tags: apache, ssl, subdomain, virtualhost

I'm having issues with a sub domain, everything gets redirected to the main domain.

DNS is setup correctly.

I'm using ssl on the main domain but not on the sub domain, the sites-available folder looks like this:

```
default-ssl.conf
example.net.conf
subdomain.example.net.conf
```

subdomain.example.net.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin info@example.net
    ServerName example.net
    DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain.example.net
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache has no errors in the log and does not complain when restarted after **a2enmod**

I never set up the ssl so I'm assuming that it is this that is causing everything to be redirected to example.net, the end of the default-ssl.conf has this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}s ^www.example.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Is this what's doing the redirect and if so how to fix it, if not where next to look?

Comment: `%{HTTP_HOST}s`? What's the `s` doing there? that'd translate into something like `example.coms` and never match

Comment: `ServerName subdomain.example.net` if you have a separated conf file like you do ..

Comment: Zak, cant upvote your comment but thanks, that was the issue.